# Docker - httpd (pid 1) already running - Docker App Windows

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile, docker-container

First of all, sorry for any mistake with my writing, (it's not my language).

My problem with docker app (using windows 10) is this msg:  httpd (pid 1) already running.

i have one container with db and web app, but the problem occours only with web container.

is there by any chance some line of command that i can use in dockerfile to remove this archive on start/stop the container?

ps: when i use docker-compose down and docker-compose up (vscode extensions) there is no problem, but when i restart the container it start again.

thanks for any kind of help.

i've been trying to use some lines in dockerfile like

RUN rm -f /run/httpd/httpd.pid but's not helping

Comment: Can you show your comand line or docker file to start the db and app container ?
And sharing your docker compose file is appreciated.